# Building Search functionality in Ruby on Rails 7

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I am new to Ruby on Rails, and I am building a search feature in my Ruby on Rails application. Below are the details:

- I have an Employee Model, View and Controller in my application.
- I intended to use Search feature to search employees by their names.
- Below are the details:

**Employee View**

```
</div></div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">

<div class="form-group">
 <%= form_with url: employees_path, class: "form-control rounded-0", method: :get do |form| %> 
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Search Employee</label>
    
      <%= text_field_tag(:employeesearchfield)  %>
       
    <%= form.submit "Search" %>
    <%end%>
  </div>
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  resources :operations
  get 'operations/:preason', to: 'operations#index'
  get 'pages/Administratorhome'
  get 'pages/userhome'
  devise_for :users
  resources :employees do 

    collection do 
    delete 'delete_multiple'
    end 
    collection do
    post 'import' 
    end
    collection do 
    get 'export'
    end
  end

  put "employees/:id", to: 'employees#show'
  

  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: "pages#Administratorhome"
  # Below route is required for logout functionality.
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'users/sign_out' => "devise/sessions#destroy"
end
  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end
```

**Employee Controller **

```
def index
   @employees = Employee.search_employee(params[:employeesearchfield])
  end
```

**Employee Model**

```
def self.search_employee(employeename)
    
    searchvar = employeename 
    
      if searchvar.nil?
        employeelist = Employee.all
      else
        employeelist = Employee.find_by(name: "searchvar")
      end  
      return employeelist
  end
```

I am getting the **NoMethod Error** when I try to search an Employee using the Search form.

[Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJHRS.png)

I am unable to understand that why the @employee instance variable is null.

I tried byebug gem and tried to find the data flow.

I found that the parameter "params[:employeesearchfield]" in the search form hasn't been flowing into this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a `undefined method 'each' for nil` on the line `@employees.each` then that means that the `@employees` variable is returning `nil`.

This happens because of this line in your model

```
employeelist = Employee.find_by(name: "searchvar")
```

because `find_by` returns only the first found record or `nil` when not found. Additionally, your query is hard coded to always search for the string `"searchvar"` not the variable `searchvar`.

To fix your issue, change the method to:

```
def self.search_employee(employee_name)
  if employee_name.nil?
    Employee.all
  else
    Employee.where(name: employee_name)
  end  
end
```

Note that you can simplify the code even further by defining a scope like this in your model:

```
scope :filter_by_name, ->(name) { where(name: name) if name }
```

and use the scope like this in your controller:

```
def index
  @employees = Employee.filter_by_name(params[:employeesearchfield])
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and support on this